# Split string (email) at @ and set as username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am extremely new to ruby on rails (5 I believe) and I am trying to split out the user from the email entered for the Devise registration system and set it as my username.

I am really at a loss on even where to get started.  (So I started here.)  I understand what I want to do and found a bit of code for ruby, but I'm not sure of how to jump to doing it in ruby on rails.  (New!)

```
@username = params[:email].split(/@/)
```

In the registration form, I am trying to create the username immediately after the email is entered.  The error I get is "undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass".  (I feel certain there are more to follow.

Comment: The error is telling you you're trying to invoke a method that's not defined in the current object you have, in this case `split` isn't a method on the Nil class. You must debug what are the values you're receiving by checking what's the value of params, a hash, if it doesn't have a email key you're gonna get nil, and hence the error.

Comment: Also, if you have `params[:email]` equal to `foo@bar.com` (which you don't, but let's go with it), then `@username = params[:email].split(/@/)` is going to give you `@username` equal to `["foo", "bar.com"]`, which is not what you want. Instead, try `@username = params[:email].split(/@/).first`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 'undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass' because params[:email] in the submitted parameter is empty, you should probably say email is mandatory. Second, if you need to extract the character before @, you can refer to using regular expressions

```rb
  str = 'example@domain.com'
  str =~ /(.*)@/
  $1 # 'example'
```